# Docker compose not passing variables to container in service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose file

```
  services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DB_USER=user
      - MYSQL_DB_PASS=password
      - MYSQL_DB_HOST="jdbc:mysql://dbhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false"
    ...
```

This is what I get when I try to run docker-compose up

```
Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
```

Everything works fine if I manually run the container passing the envs

```
docker run --network backend -e MYSQL_DB_USER="user" -e MYSQL_DB_PASS="pass" -e MYSQL_DB_HOST="jdbc:mysql://dbhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false" -it api:1.0
```

The dockerfile for the API service is multi-staging and is using ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: Are you rebuilding the image/container if you run it? I'd probably try deleting both the container and image and creating it again from docker compose.

Comment: Delete your local image and try again. Java, spring boot and docker works very well. Could you share your code or at least a reproducible sample ( App.java with a single queryl ?

Comment: @MalwareMoon you are correct. The `"` around the  jdbc connection was causing the problem. Thank you

Comment: Was I? After I rechecked it, I thought it was OK after all, I will write you an answer. Edit: Or not seeing that there is a good one already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the double quotes around the environment value

```yaml
environment:
  - MYSQL_DB_HOST=jdbc:mysql://dbhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
```

From the error message, you can see that the JDBC layer expects *something* to have removed the quotes before you run the application.  And indeed if you were running this in a shell

```bash
export MYSQL_DB_HOST="jdbc:...?autoReconnect=true&..."
```

the shell would remove the double quotes, and they're important there because the `?` and `&` are both "special" characters in shell syntax.

YAML has fewer "special" characters and you often don't need to quote strings (depending on syntax).  It's also the case that the shell will handle quoted substrings of a command, but within a single YAML value, either the whole value needs to be quoted or none of it.

Compose supports two different forms of [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment).  It can either be a list of `KEY=value` single YAML strings, or a YAML mapping `KEY: value`.  In the dictionary form it would be acceptable to quote the values (but probably not necessary here).

So also correct:

```yaml
environment:
  # quote the _whole_ string, but not just part of it
  # (only necessary if your string closely resembles other YAML syntax)
  - "MYSQL_DB_HOST=jdbc:..."
```

```yaml
environment:
  # as a mapping, quoting nothing
  # (all environment variables must use this syntax)
  MYSQL_DB_HOST: jdbc:...
```

```yaml
environment:
  # as a mapping, quoting the value
  MYSQL_DB_HOST: "jdbc:..."
```