# Database `my-db` does not exist on the database server at `db:3306`

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, backend, prisma

I have two Docker containers, one for the backend (Node.js) and another for the MySQL database. I managed to connect the two, as I received the error "Make sure the database is running at port 3306" when changing the Prisma URL from db:3306 to localhost:3306, indicating that the connection was established correctly.

However, after verifying the connection, I am facing a new problem when trying to establish the Prisma connection with the database container. I receive the error "Database itm-db does not exist on the database server at db:3306".

[Soo i had to verify if the database 'itm-db' was created inside mysql container, and it was there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW89V.png)

Here is my configuration

```
Prisma Schema---------

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = "mysql://root:mypass@db:3306/itm-db"
}

Docker Compose-----------
version: '3'
    services:
      backend:
        build:
          context: ./Backend
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - '3000:3000'
        depends_on:
          - db
        volumes:
          - ./Backend:/app
      db:
        image: mysql:latest
        restart: always
        environment:
          - MYSQL_DATABASE="itm-db"
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
          - '3306:3306'
        expose:
          - '3306'
        volumes:
          - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      frontend:
        build:
          context: ./Frontend
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - '80:80'
        environment:
          - VITE_API_URL=http://backend:3000
        volumes:
          - './Frontend:/app'
    
    volumes:
      mysql_data:
```

Any insights into what might be causing the issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to verifiy if 'itm-db' was created inside container and i tried to remove all volumes and images and create from scratch

Comment: Hey, could you explain why ? Docker doesnt create shared network between services when you dont specify network ? However i tried to do this aproach using driver bridge. But the same problem occurred again 'Database `itm-db` does not exist on the database server at `db:3306`.'

Comment: Your database is named `"itm-db"` including double quotes as part of the database name.  You need to delete the double quotes in the `MYSQL_DATABASE` setting, they're not read as special characters in that context.  (And then `docker-compose down -v` to delete the underlying Docker volume to cause that variable to be used on startup.)  Also see [Docker compose not passing variables to container in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74417928/docker-compose-not-passing-variables-to-container-in-service).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post helped me:[Docker compose not passing variables to container in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74417928/docker-compose-not-passing-variables-to-container-in-service)

The problem wasnt the network as docker can handle communication on containers created on the same docker compose file. The problem was how i wrote environments variables. Quotes are not special characters on this context.

Wrong

```
environment:
  - my_enveiroment:"1234"
```

Right

```
environment:
  - my_enveiroment:1234
```